# How to delete 10 records out of 20 records and display the remaining 10 records in an xslt?

Tags: xslt

I'm a fresher in xslt coding..I'm able to delete a particular record using remove() operation but I'm unable to delete 10 records out of 20 records at a time and display the remaining 10 records...Can anyone please give me an example of performing this operation..Thanks in advance.

Actually I'm doing project in dataower, I'm giving soap request and I want to delete 10 records from the response using xslt code..

Here is my input request...

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Body>
<IntegrationEventWS_GetEvents_Input>
<EventCount>10</EventCount>
<QueueName>Opportunity Partner</QueueName></IntegrationEventWS_GetEvents_Input>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my sample response...

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Like this in the response I have 20 records...and I want to delete 10 out of 20 records at a time..for this I have to write xslt code..

Here is my xslt code...I tried like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>id</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl: remove select="artist"/>
       <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
         </tr>          
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and I used remove() to delete the entire records..

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Show us what you have done.

Comment: Show us your input XML, the expected output XML, and your current XSLT.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Does the response always include exactly 20 records? If yes, which 10 of those do you want to keep? Also, you say "*delete 10 out of 20 records **at a time***" - what exactly does that mean? There are no "times" in XSLT.

Comment: delete 10 out of 20 records at a time means....I want to delete all 10 records at once...I don't want to delete 1 by 1...and I have exactly 20 records..I need to delete those records which gets updated...suppose 10 records got updated out of 20..then all those 10 records should be deleted at once..

Comment: I am afraid that makes very little sense, esp. this part: "*I need to delete those records which gets updated*". I don't know what you mean by "*records which gets updated*".